# If the determinant of a square matrix is not zero, is the matrix surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

I believe that if the determinant is not zero, then the matrix would be full rank, so the matrix would be subjective. Is this true for square matrices?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is indeed true for square matrices.

(Note that some people use a matrix and the corresponding transformation synonymously, however sometimes $\varphi_A$ (or another letter like $f_A$) is used to refer to the transformation and A to refer to the matrix corresponding to said transformation and vice versa. In that case one would say, that $\varphi_A$ is indeed surjective under said circumstances)

A line of argument could be as follows:
Let $A \in K^{n \times n}$.

If the  $det(A) \neq 0$, it follows, that A is invertible. If an inverse exists, A is a bijection and as such also surjective.

Another way to argue could be, that:
If the  $det(A) \neq 0$, it follows, that A is invertible. As a result $Rank(A)=n$. Note that the Rank is the dimension of the linear span of the rows/columns. Since the dimension  of the linear span of the columns of A is n, it follows that A is surjective.

Hope that helped